# I'm trying to draw a map made out of polygons using UIBezierPath, but the performance is terrible

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath

I'm new to iOS and Objective-C and would like to understand what I'm doing wrong and what would be the best way to do what I'm trying to do.

I'm trying to draw a map made out of polygons. Right now I'm using `UIBezierPath` to draw it. I draw about 88 polygons using `moveToPoint` and `addLineToPoint`and then fill it with a random color. However some of these polygons have over 1000 lines. The whole map has over 30,000 lines. I'm doing this inside `MapView`'s `drawRect`.

Right now the whole project is structured like this:

`ViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` initiates a `MapView`(inherits from `UIView`) and adds it as a subView, like this:

```
    self.pview = [[MapView alloc]init];
    self.pview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height );
    [self.view addSubview:pview];
```

`MapView` loads the csv file into several `Poly` objects that are added to a `NSMutableArray`. A `Poly` has the X/Y coordinates (floats, I'm using `CGFloat`).

`MapView`'s drawRect looks like this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
    int oldtemp = 0;
    UIBezierPath* path;
    UIColor* fillColor;
    path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    for (int i = 0; i < [polys count]; i++){
        poly *p = [polys objectAtIndex:i];
        int temp = p.getPolyid.intValue;
        if (temp == oldtemp){
            [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake([p.getx floatValue]+posx, [p.gety floatValue]+posy)]; // more about posx/posy after this code block
        }else{
            [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake([p.getx floatValue]+posx, [p.gety floatValue]+posy)];
            fillColor = [UIColor blueColor]; // not using a random color here, performance is still bad
            }
        }
    [path closePath];
    [fillColor setFill];
    [path fill];
}
```

`posx` and `posy` are `CGFloat`s. `ViewController`'s `touchesMoved` sends the x/y coordinates to `MapView`'s `-(void)moveX:(CGFloat)x Y:(CGFloat)y{`. This method looks like this:

```
-(void)moveX:(CGFloat)x Y:(CGFloat)y{
    if (x > initx){
        posx += (x - initx);
    }else{
        posx -= (initx - x);
    }
    if (y > inity){
        posy += (y - inity);
    }else{
        posy -= (inity - y);
    }
    initx = x;
    inity = y;
    [self setNeedsDisplay]; //should this be here? My map doesn't redraw without it.
}
```

All this results in a map that is drawn maybe once every 2 seconds and leaves a blinking trail behind it.

How can I fix this?

Comment: If you are using MKMapView (and not a custom map view): Is the moveX:Y: method used only to move the drawn lines as the user pans to keep in sync with the underlying map?  Have you tried using MapKit's MKPolygon overlay instead?

Comment: The moveX:Y is just for moving the lines. But I'm not using MKMapView or MKPolygon. It's just an UIView with a custom DrawRect.